# How to put a static website made with HTML/CSS into Opencart

Tags: php, html, css, opencart

I have a static webiste (e-commerce/some pages) made with HTML/CSS a little bit of jQuery and I want to put it on Opencart to make it dynamic, I have some knowledge of PHP, I'm currently learning the language. I was wondering if you guys could help me with some information or tutorials on this subject.

This is my structure (if it helps):
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn your HTML in a opencart template. Here is a good start:

https://code.tutsplus.com/series/create-a-custom-theme-with-opencart--cms-662